# Drupal 7 - Handling multiple type of users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to create a website for a client using Drupal 7, the only problem is that I don't know how to handle multiples login forms and permissions.

The goal is that A type of user must be allowed to browse and do some stuff on the website but they can't post offers, however B type of users can only post their offers and manage their contents, the system is just as Upwork.

How can I achieve this ? I'm not good at PHP but I know how to use Drupal, so are there modules that can help me to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how Drupal works by default using role based permissions. You won't need to install a module or have different login forms.

Start by creating different roles. RoleA can view certain content types and maybe post comments. RoleB can do everything RoleA can do plus post offers and manage their own content. You can control create/edit/delete permissions by content type. It can all be done using the point and click admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

On admin page `/admin/user` (root relative path to admin page) you can see your site users. There's also link "+ Add user" for creating new user. So if you edit/create an user, on user edit page there is a section "Roles" where you can set what roles that user can use. One role may be "Browse some stuff" and other "Edit some stuff".. You can add/edit roles at admin page `/admin/people/permissions/roles`. So create the roles you need there.

And to precisely set what role can do what there is admin page: `/admin/people/permissions`. So when you create all the roles you need, go to that page to set permissions and after that you can assign roles to your users.